# how do you change the directory of imports in cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, python-import, cx-freeze, python-importlib

I am trying to make an exe via cx_Freeze, but the "everything you import is in the `lib` directory" is annoying specially because I am attempting to add add-on functionality to my app by using this code in order to load everything from a folder

```py
mod_list = {}

for mod in os.scandir(os.path.join("mods")):
    if mod.is_dir():
        try:
            for file in os.scandir(os.path.join("mods", mod.name, "scripts")):
                if file.is_file() and file.name.endswith(".py"):
                    mod = importlib.import_module(f'mods.{mod.name}.scripts.AI.{file.name[:-3]}')
                    mod_list[mod.__name__[mod.__name__.index(".", mod.__name__.index(".")+1)+1:]] = mod
        except:
            continue
```

which cx_Freeze does not include in its `lib` directory

What I'm basically saying is if there is a way to change it from the default `lib` directory to a specified directory without the rest of the modules being placed there. And, if possible, is it possible to make it use `.py` files instead of `.pyc`?